# Import data to a temporary database and rename it when finished with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have a process that imports from a XLS file data to a database in a MVC Application that I would like to simplify.

At the moment, the process checks, for each record in each table in the database, if the record:

- 1 - Is new -> then is inserted;
- 2 - Has changed - > then the database is updated;

Then the process remove every record that is in the database and not in the XLS file.

To simplify the process, I would like to insert the XLS record in a Blank database, and then, "switch" them so I don't have to do all the checking I refered previously.

My problem is that I don't know how to manage the trade between the old database and the new one based on the Querystring:

```
<add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Database=DB;UID=user;pwd=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And the Datacontext:

```
    public DbContext() : base("DB") 
    {
        // Tells Entity Framework that we will handle the creation of the database manually for all the projects in the solution
        Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
    }
```

Comment: `for each record in each table in the database` that sounds scary..Did you mean a single table.

Comment: Hi thanks! Yes that's correct, in the XLS file comes all the new data for the next day of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Use the answer I wrote in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380352/problems-with-web-config-and-app-config).
Add a secundary constructor or something like that in order to change the connection string, then use this new system settings to store a list of all connections strings and add two variables: actualDB, newDB.
Then after making those actions, you just need to write a code that opens the xml file, changes the actualDB to the value of the newDB (and cleans ups this one too).

And from that moment, you reload the value of the actualDB with the new one.